# Background color for `code` in comments on mobile

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, mobile-web, user-experience

The Stack Overflow mobile site got new colors (and fonts?) a few days back. On the whole I like the overhaul, but now, **it's hard to see whether text in comments  is `code` formatted** or not. Could we please get back the lavenderish grey background color which previously made it easy, or at least possible, to see the difference?

[image]

Comment: Nice freehand circles there

Comment: Even the non-comment version isn't that clear to me.

Comment: `example for all`.

Comment: On a related note, it would be nice to have a distinct background colour for code in chat rooms...

Comment: thanks for report, i will take a look at this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've updated mobile CSS a little - code elements are now more easily distinguished in comments.

Thanks again for reporting this.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)